# Redux-saga put method doesn't trigger reducer

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, saga

I'm trying to trigger a redux reducer by calling put method in my redux saga, but it doesn't get triggered, even if I return same action type which should be caught in my reducer.

This is my saga:

```
export function* registrationSaga(action) {
  try {
    const response = yield call(registerUser, action.payload);
    console.log(response)
    yield put({ type: REGISTER_USER_SUCCESS, response })
  } catch(error) {
    yield put({ type: REGISTER_USER_ERROR, error });
  }
}
```

And this is my reducer:

```
export const registrationReducer = (state = {}, action) => {
let response = action.response;

switch(action.type) {
  case REGISTER_USER_SUCCESS: {
    console.log("successful registration")
    return { ...state, registration_success: response.success, registration_message: response.message };
  }

  case REGISTER_USER_ERROR:
    return { ...state, registration_success: response.success, registration_message: response.message };
  default:
    return state;
}
}
```

I expect to see "successful registration" in my console and to get that response as prop in my component, but that doesn't happen. What should cause this problem?

Here are my rootReducer and store also:

```
const rootReducer = () => combineReducers({
    registrationReducer,
    todoReducer
})

export default rootReducer;
```

and store:

```
const sagaMiddleware = createSagaMiddleware()

export const store = createStore(
    rootReducer,
    applyMiddleware(sagaMiddleware)
);

sagaMiddleware.run(rootSaga)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`rootReducer` should not be a *function* that calls `combineReducers`, it should be the return value of `combineReducers` instead:

```
const rootReducer = combineReducers({
    registrationReducer,
    todoReducer,
});

export default rootReducer;
```

[Redux API](https://redux.js.org/api/combinereducers)